Is it mandatory to use "@" infront of concat function in ADF expression builder?
Is below two expression both are correct? Or is there any specific use case where we need to use @ before concat function

concat('khkjhj','fhgf')
@concat('hhjhj','jhg')


In case if concat is the initial function within your expression builder, then you need to append @ in front of it.
so basically any beginning function within the expression must have @ in front of it.
And function used post that, needs to be called as is without @.
eg :
@string(int(variablex))
If you use concat without @, below would be your output

it would consider it as a string as is and not function as a Function.

I used concat function in expression builder without @ in the begining but its not showing any syntax error and the result also coming correctly.

@DIP have updated the answer with image. without @, it would consider it as a string as is and not function as an expression
